# Error `could not load host key` when trying to recreate SSH host keys

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am trying to recreate the ssh-server host keys.

I have at least two ways to do this:

- **With dpkg-reconfigure**

  ```
  dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
  ```

  This works fine, but I cannot give the key length then. I want for example 4096 for the RSA key.
- **Manually with ssh-keygen**

  ```
  sudo ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N 'myverylongpasswordhere' -b 4096 -t rsa
  ```

  This recreates me the keys, but after restarting the server, I receive the following **error message**:

  ```
  could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
  ```

  so I checked the sshd_config file whats in there:

  ```
  HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
  ```

  matches perfectly. So, I checked the owner and rights to all my keys

  ```
  -rw------- 1 root root 3326 Mär 24 08:57 ssh_host_rsa_key
  ```

  When I remove all keys and recreate them with `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`, the keys are smaller and having the same file-rights like above.

**Question:** How can I use `dpkg-reconfigure` with keylengh 4096 for RSA?

Comment: Please run `sshd` in debug mode from the command line (`sudo sshd -d`) for more info on the issue and post the output.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That looks like a good suggestion. I tried recreating the issue by moving my keys temporarily, creating new keys with passwords, stopping and restarting... I don't get the error message of the OP. This is the result I get `livewire@za20:/etc/ssh$ sudo sshd -d` output
`sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path` Otherwise I would have included an example in my answer :(

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d`. The error you got is meant literally (though not quite clear).

Comment: Even though the accepted answer solves the problem, I'm still wondering about the final question in the first post: How can I use `dpkg-reconfigure` with keylength 4096? Is there a config file somewhere that contains this info? I looked around in the debconf databases (in `/var/cache/debconf/`) but didn't find anything that looked like the keylength.

Comment: Docker way: `RUN ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> sudo ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N 'myverylongpasswordhere' -b 4096 -t rsa
> ```
>
> recreates me the keys. but, after restarting the server, i recieve
>
> ```
> could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
> ```

You create a hostkey with a password. Is there any customization to unlock that hostkey? If not, then I think that is what is to be expected: the script that manages the service starts up, tries to load the hostkey, and fails. As far as I know you shouldn't create hostkeys protected with passwords.

If you are interested in hardening your SSH server then I recommend reading https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html the command used to create the hostkey in that document is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ssh_host_rsa_key
```

But you should read the entire document before making any changes.

Comment: works. just removing the myverylongpasswordhere.
by the way: really nice article to read. in fact openssh comes from ubuntu-repro in my case, and did not support 
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

Answer (score 56):

None of the answers above worked for me. I fixed my ubuntu system by doing the following:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
```

Comment: THIS. This is the real answer, as confirmed by the manpage for ssh-keygen about that "-A" flag: 

For each of the key types (rsa1, rsa, dsa, ecdsa and ed25519) for which host keys do not exist, generate the host keys with the default key file path, an
             empty passphrase, default bits for the key type, and default comment.  This is used by system administration scripts to generate new host keys.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed, this is the simplest

Comment: Dude, just logged in to say thank you! My ssh keys could not be read. This regenerated my keys.  Restarted my ssh server and all worked!

Comment: It DID work on my WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

`ssh-keygen` generates an SSH key.

- `-t` specifies the type of key to create
- `-b` specifies the number of bits in the key.

See [this page](http://securit.se/2012/01/english-configure-ssh-high-security/) for more information.

Comment: this is not the answer. please see my question, i allready did this, with the resulst that hostkey could not be loaded.

Comment: @EmilSommer No, that exactly **is** the answer, just missing an explanation (why you get the error message and what it means).