# Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key in /var/log/auth.log

Tags: server, ssh, security, authentication

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 instance running on AWS.

I was browsing the auth logs (`/var/log/auth.log*`), and noticed the following line appearing:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

This line appears between 1k-10k times a day, presumably due to failed hack attempts.

In researching this problem, I came up with a number of questions.

What is the effect of the absence of this key? I can still log in fine with the key provided by AWS. Is it forcing the security of my SSH connections to be downgraded? Has it been disabled on purpose because of security concerns?

I've seen some people suggest that the key wasn't generated correctly during installation, and that I need to regenerate the key with [`dpkg-reconfigure` or `ssh-keygen`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600584).

Alternatively, I've also seen people recommend just commenting out the line: `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can generate the missing hostkey via:

```
ssh-keygen -A
```

`ed25519` is a bit faster and more secure. It's not necessary and, aside from logspam, this doesn't have that much effect. You could, indeed, comment out `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key`, without much effect. But, at the same time, `ed25519 is a good host-key format to support.

Comment: After that, I also had to restart the ssh service:  sudo service ssh restart

Comment: I had empty files for `dsa`, `ecdsa` and `ed25519` that I had to delete for `ssh-keygen -A` to do anything

Answer (score 0):

If you are running FIPS mode when you run `ssh-keygen -A` you will see an error like:

`ED25519 keys are not allowed in FIPS mode`

So the appropriate action on a FIPS server is to disable this HostKey type in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Comment out the line like this:
`# HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key`

Then restart SSHD: `service sshd restart`

No more log spam.